# Runtime error when using pytorch convolutional model

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to develop a covid-19 classification model. The images dataset I used is of shape torch.Size([100, 3, 224, 224]). When trying to run my model I'm getting this runtime error message(as shown in the image).
Any help to understand and fix the issue, please.
this is the code

```
class CovidCnnModel(ImageClassificationBase):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.network = nn.Sequential(
      # nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size =(3,3), padding=1),
        nn.Conv2d(3, out_channels = 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2), # output: 64 x 16 x 16

        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2), # output: 128 x 8 x 8

        nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2), # output: 256 x 4 x 4

        nn.Flatten(), 
        nn.Linear(256*4*4, 1024),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(1024, 512),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(512, 2))
    
def forward(self, xb):
    return self.network(xb)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your input is of size `224x224` while your network is designed for ``128x128` (judging by the comments in the code).